# How can I use an Java EE API in a Java project?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I'm reading about the Java API for Json Processing, specified in [ths site.](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr353/index.html) However, when I try to test such code like:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileInputStream(...));
```

I can't, cause neither `JsonReader` class or `Json` class can't be imported from nowhere. I only get some `JsonParser` class which is imported from `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.json.JsonParser` but obviously it isn't what I'm trying to get.

I have Java EE installed and I'm working with the Java EE version of Netbeans. How can I seize these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the download page for the reference implementation jar of JSR-000353

https://java.net/projects/jsonp/downloads/directory/ri

If you are using JSON I recommend the Jackson JSON library.

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

The jar files can be found here:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

For further information on the difference in implementations please see this question
[Differentiating the Jersey, Jackson, and JaxB APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459984/differentiating-the-jersey-jackson-and-jaxb-apis)

Comment: Well, as it's part of the Java EE version, shouldn't it be at reach from the core libraries?

Comment: Yes, if you have the full EE libraries installed.  The library will be there but if you don't want to include the full JAX-RS libraries, just use this set of jars.  I can look up which jar it is in if you want.

Comment: Yes, please, where can I find it. And, These libraries will be at reach ONLY under a EE like project? Not under a simple Java Application?

Comment: See edit above.  I gave the url for the reference of this actual library and for the Jackson JSON library.

Comment: A god resource for tracking down where you can find a jar file is: http://www.findjar.com/index.x  Just type in the class you are looking for and a list of possible jars will come up.

Comment: How can I "add" this feature to a Java SE project once I downloaded the library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37846/discussion-between-diego-and-emmentaler)

Comment: It's weird though, that such an important API is not included in Java SE (although, various XML processing API are included in core libraries).

Answer (score 1):

JSR 353 was released along with the Java EE 7 platform. JsonObject and JsonReader API can be used in two different ways:

- Use a Java EE 7 compliant application server, such as [GlassFish 4](http://glassfish.org). In this case, the API is built in to the runtime and will be resolved correctly for you. You can use NetBeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ and if the server runtime is configured properly then it just works.
- Alternatively, you can download the Reference Implementation from http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr353/index.html and integrate wit your application or container of your choice.

A good set of samples for using this API are available at https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/tree/master/json.

Answer (score -1):

To use [JSON Processing](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-json-processing-json-p-api/) in a Maven project you can use the following Maven coordinates:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Or to include all of Java EE 8 add the following coordinates:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

JSON Processing 1.1 includes new [JSON Pointer](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/java-ee-8-json-processing-1-1-json-pointer-overview/), [JSON Patch](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/java-ee-8-json-processing-1-1-json-patch-overview/) and [JSON Merge](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/java-ee-8-json-processing-1-1-json-merge-patch-overview/).